# hexfloat and MinGW?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, mingw

the following program crashes when compiled and run in MinGW (it displays the "a.exe has stopped working" Windows dialogue):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double pi{3.1415926535};
    cout << hexfloat << pi << endl;
}
```

The following program produces the output 2e-081:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << hexfloat << 100.0 << endl;
}
```

Have I misunderstood how to use hexfloat?

This is with version 6.3.0-1 of MinGW and gcc 6.3.0, using --std=c++11.

Comment: Hard to say if you misunderstand. What were you expecting? [Unable to reproduce either result](https://ideone.com/4Ps6V0), by the way. Could be differences in the floating point encoding.

Comment: I was expecting output that contained a hexadecimal representation of the data. I certainly wasn't expecting a crash!

Comment: That's reasonable. I don't have a match for your version of MinGW and I can't reproduce with GCC6.3, so I can offer you nothing useful.

Comment: Use MinGW-w64 instead. The old minGW is poorly maintained

Comment: I am using MinGW-w64.